# Integer not casting "08" and "09"

Tags: ruby

Why, in ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x86_64-darwin20], this is happening?

```
irb(main):001:0> Integer("01")
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> Integer("02")
=> 2
irb(main):003:0> Integer("03")
=> 3
irb(main):004:0> Integer("04")
=> 4
irb(main):005:0> Integer("05")
=> 5
irb(main):006:0> Integer("06")
=> 6
irb(main):007:0> Integer("07")
=> 7
irb(main):008:0> Integer("08")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):8
        1: from (irb):8:in `Integer'
ArgumentError (invalid value for Integer(): "08")
irb(main):009:0> Integer("09")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        6: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        5: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        4: from /Users/sig/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        3: from (irb):8
        2: from (irb):9:in `rescue in irb_binding'
        1: from (irb):9:in `Integer'
ArgumentError (invalid value for Integer(): "09")
```

Comment: Please post the output here as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: And what is the output of `Integer("010")`, `Integer("011")`, `Integer"012")`, etc. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: What does that happen? And what should I do to get 08 and 09?

Comment: "And what should I do to get 08 and 09? " I don't understand. You never get `04` or `05` so why would you expect to get `08` or `09`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A leading zero indicates an octal (radix 8) integer.

- 07 - valid octal integer seven
- 08 - invalid octal integer, the least significant digit is invalid

Instead, you probably want to specify decimal (radix 10) integers.

- 7 - valid decimal integer seven
- 8 - valid decimal integer eight

Comment: 08 is not valid. 7 is the maximum value of an octal digit.

Comment: Thanks Mark, corrected.

Comment: Alternatively, ` Integer("08", 10)` works as expected.